# Настройка ядра для TIME_WAIT - не срабатывает

Tags: linux, сеть, ip, tcp, ядро

При большом кол-ве кратких соединений единовременно, заканчиваются сокеты с сообщением:

> 'Cannot assign requested address'

Если посмотреть на кол-во соединений в состоянии TIME_WAIT, их будет большое кол-во. (больше чем разрешено, в настройках ядра возможно отрытых портов)

```
netstat -nat | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n |grep 'TIME_WAIT'
25995 TIME_WAIT #Во время проблем их больше
```

Пробовал уменьшить время жизни для данного типа соединений и включил переиспользование портов

```
 sysctl -a |grep -E 'tcp_fin|tcp_tw'
 net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 5
 net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0
 net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 0
```

Но, если выполнить пробное соединение со стороны клиента допустим к mysql серверу, то я вижу на стороне сервера, что соединение висит.

```
# На стороне клиента:
mysql -h my_remote.server.ru # на стороне клиента 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'80.80.80.80' (using password: NO)
#На стороне сервера:
netstat -nat | grep 80.80.80.80 |grep 3306 |grep TIME_WAIT #Тут видим, что соединение висит более 50сек.
```

Хотя, если посмотреть на спецификацию протокола tcp, то:

> TIME-WAIT Узел-1 получил сегмент с флагом FIN, отправил сегмент с флагом ACK и ждёт 2*MSL секунд, перед окончательным закрытием соединения

Что я не понимаю, или почему настройки ядра не срабатывают?

Comment: возможно, опечатка: *включил переиспользование портов* — насколько я понимаю, вы как раз **выключили** переиспользование портов.

Comment: @alexander barakin Не совсем опечатка, я хотел показать текущие настройки с которыми я проверяю, что происходит. Т.е. отключил специально, на данный момент. А в обычной жизни они в состоянии - True